# can't find 'udevd' binary in ubuntu docker image

Tags: docker, udev

I am currently following a guide for a ubuntu based docker container.
Guide: https://joshh.info/2017/xserver-in-docker-revisited/

In there the author is using `udevd` and `udevadm`. For the latter I have a binary available but for `udevd` I always end up in a `command not found`.

These are the commands used:

```
$ docker run -it --privileged debian /bin/bash
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install xserver-xorg xorg jwm
$ udevd --debug &
$ udevadm trigger
<lots of output, brace yourself>
$ startx
```

I wonder if anybody here can get this working.
However when trying to figure out how to at least download `udev` I only find an information (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/udev/) that it's included in the ubuntu base. So I can't find a way to download it and no way to use

Anybody an idea what I am not understanding here?

PS: I know there is no such thing as a `udev` binary. But `udevd` should be available since the author is using it in his script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`udev` become part of `systemd`

Try:

```
/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --debug &
```

Source: [Comment from OP referenced guide](http://disq.us/p/1qqj035)